# Why is there a race condition in this program?

Tags: go, race-condition, goroutine

I'm looking at the [typical data races](http://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html#Typical_Data_Races) in the Golang documentation, and I don't quite understand why there is a problem with this program:

```
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(5)
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        go func() {
            fmt.Println(i) // Not the 'i' you are looking for.
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

It prints `5, 5, 5, 5, 5` when I would expect it to print `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` (not necessarily in this order).

The way I see it, when the goroutine gets created inside the loop, the value of `i` is known (for instance, one could do a `log.Println(i)` at the beginning of the loop and see the expected value). So I would expect the goroutine to capture the value of `i` when it gets created and use that later on.

Obviously it's not what's happening but why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your function literal references the `i` from the outer scope. If you request the value of `i`, you get the value of whatever `i` is right now. In order to use the value of `i` at the time the Go routine was created, supply an argument:

```
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(5)
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        go func(i int) {
            fmt.Println(i)
            wg.Done()
        }(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

[runnable example](http://play.golang.org/p/O-kjsQ2D8D)

Answer (score 2):

The variable `i` is not declared within the function literal, so it becomes part of a closure. An easy way how to understand closures is to think about how can they be implemented. The simple solution is using a pointer. You can think that the function literal is rewritten by the compiler into some

```
func f123(i *int) {
        fmt.Println(*i)
        wg.Done            
}
```

- On invocation of this function, by the go statement, the address of the `i` variable is passed to the called f123 (example name generated by the compiler).
- You're probably using default GOMAXPROCS==1, so the for loop executes 5 times without any scheduling as the loop does no I/O or other "schedule points", such as channel operations.
- When the loop terminates, with `i == 5`, the `wg.Wait` finally triggers execution of the five, ready to run, goroutines (for f123). All of them have of course the same pointer to the same integer variable `i`.
- Every goroutine now sees the same `i` value of 5.

You might get different output when running with GOMAXPROCS > 1, or when the loop yields control. That can be done also by, for example, [runtime.Gosched](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Gosched).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, your variable `i` is used inside the goroutines that you're created, but those goroutines could execute way in the future, once your loop is already done looping.  At this point, the value of `i` is not `5`, and all your go routines get kicked up, read the value of `i` (as `5`) and continue on their merry way.

I believe FUZxxl mentioned the use of passing the value `i` as an argument to the function.  I think this is a good idea for rather complicated systems, specially if the function you're kicking a go routine for is not an inline closure.  However, in most cases, I think it's a lot cleaner to just create a new temporary variable for each go routine:

http://play.golang.org/p/6dnkrEGfhn

```
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(5)
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        myi := i
        go func() {
            fmt.Println(myi)
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

The effect is the same, and it could be argued that it's a matter of preference, and it is.  This is my preference :p